# Set ng-model value inside the AngularJs Controller

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working in a project with springboot backend and angularJs frontend.
In my front end I need to update user name in a prompt dialog. I'm using $mdDialog.

I've created the function for the prompt dialog.

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(ev) {
    HomeService.updateCustomer($scope.customer)
    var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
      .title('Edit User Name')
      .textContent($scope.customerName)
      .placeholder('User Name')
      .ariaLabel('CustomerName')
      .initialValue($scope.customerName)
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .required(true)
      .ok('Save!')
      .cancel('Discard');

    $mdDialog.show(confirm)
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.status = 'UserName has been updated!' + result;
    }, 
    function() {
      $scope.status = 'UserName has not been updated';
    });
  };
```

Now I want to add below html content in to the prompt dialog to get user input and I want to submit that values in to the database.

Here is my html codes.

```
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>

            <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" type="text" ng-model="customer.customerName" required>

    </div>
    <button id="button" type="reset" name="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"   ng-click="updateCustomer(customer)" ng-disabled= "registrationForm.$invalid">Register</button>

</fieldset>
```

Other important codes.

```
  $scope.updateCustomer = function(){
   HomeService.updateCustomer($scope.customer)
    .then (function success(response){ 
        $scope.message = response.data.customerName + " Updated";
        $scope.errorMessage = '';
    },
  );

};
```

HomeService.js

```
 this.updateCustomer = function updateCustomer(){
        return $http.put(REST_SERVICE_URI+'update' , customer)
    }
```

or I need to bind the value of "result" into $scope.customer

Comment: You're missing a semi colon on the updateCustomer call

Comment: @Tharuka: this.updateCustomer = function updateCustomer(){   should be this.updateCustomer = function(){. Once this is changed, please update the question that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want like this.

```
    $scope.updateCustomer = function(){
    HomeService.updateCustomer($scope.customer)
        .then (function success(response){ 
            $scope.customer = response.data;
            $scope.message = response.data.customerName + " Updated";
            $scope.errorMessage = '';
        },
    );

}
```